# Material rendering black

Tags: rendering, shaders

By that I mean things with a specific shader are rendering black, though the shader will render if I disconnect everything except ye olde diffuse, glossy, and mix shaders

For brevity, [here's the blend.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rcg5oe7j64jqxnp/Darkspire16.blend?dl=0%20%22here's%20the%20blend.)

Today, I rendered again just to reaffirm the problem, but the model did render for some reason. At this point the shader was the exact one in the blend file I linked. Again, still an exceedingly simple shader at this point.

But when I attempt to plug something into the material output's displacement (I wanted to try the same texture data used in the mix shader's fac input, if it matters), the model renders black again.

- The shader's preview in the outliner panel shows up properly

---

Comment: Looks like it's important what exactly are you connecting to Displacement input of the Material Output node. Probably the displacement is so big that the mesh becomes black; or it's incorrect node connected altogether.

Comment: A voronoi texture. If I were displacing things into oblivion, my material preview would likely look odd as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you are asking.

I took a look at your blend file and the only thing missing was a light. I just added a sun lamp and everything seemed fine. I noticed you had some emission shaders on some layers and not on others. Also the emission shader you did have was very far away and not pointed in the correct direction. It was lighting up nothing.

[image]
[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Might be unconventional, but that emitter lights my scene just fine:

http://imgur.com/a/KjMMK

Comment: Ok then I dont know what the problem is. The material renders fine for me. I just get a black screen because there is not enough light in the scene.

Comment: Odd. When I render, I never get a black screen. The only things that show up black are those with the problematic material. The other objects show up exactly as they do in the material-less render above.

Thanks anyway.